# subfig package not referencing sub fig labels correctly

Tags: cross-referencing, subfig

I am using the subfig package to display two plots using the code below:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \subfloat[Singular 
Terms\label{secondring:subfig-1}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth] 
{ring2branch124lowlim.pdf}
              }
 \hfill
 \subfloat[Analytic 
 Terms\label{secondring:subfig-2}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth] 
 {ring2branch124highlim.pdf}
 }
     \\
     \hfill
 \caption{Root Test Results for $\{1,2,4\}$ 
  branch in Second Annular Region}
 \label{figure:secondring}
 \end{figure}
```

and the figures display with captions:
(A) Analytic Terms  and (B) Singular Terms.

However when I reference the sub figures using for example:

```
 \ref{secondring:subfig-1}
```

the reference shows up as lower case like 6a and not 6A.

Can someone help me get the reference to agree with the actual sub fig label format?

Comment: it is always best to produce a small but complete document that shows the problem (you can use `example-image` as the image so people can run the document) the problem will be in code not shown, where you set up counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `subfig` package, the default numbering system for `subfigure` items uses lowercase alphabetic characters, e.g., `(a)`, `(b)`, etc. In contrast, your document appears to use `(A)`, `(B)`, etc to "number" consecutive `subfigure` items within a given `figure`. Put differently, your document must contain some `subfig`-relevant code that you didn't mention in your query.

A remedy would be to get rid of this special code and, instead, to insert the instruction

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}}
```

somewhere in the preamble, *after* loading the `subfig` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} % omit 'draft' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}} % <-- new

\usepackage{cleveref} % package to generate "clever" cross-reference call-outs.
\crefname{subfigure}{subfigure}{subfigures}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{5} % just for this example

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[Singular Terms\label{secondring:subfig-1}]{%
     \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]
     {ring2branch124lowlim.pdf}}
 \hfill
\subfloat[Analytic Terms\label{secondring:subfig-2}]{%
     \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth] 
     {ring2branch124highlim.pdf}}
\caption{Root Test Results for $\{1,2,4\}$ branch in Second Annular Region}
\label{figure:secondring}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{secondring:subfig-1,secondring:subfig-2}.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The AtBeginDocument command solved the problem.  Very thorough.  Also led me to cref and cleveref which looks interesting.